# How can I center a flex-element with unknown width that is not a button-element with CSS?

Tags: html, css

There's a style for a button, that can be applied to `a`-elements and `button`-elements:

```css
.button {
  appearance: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<a class="button">a-element</a>
<button class="button" type="button">a-element</button>
```

While this works fine, there's a difference in rendering:

- the `a`-element has 100 % width of the parent container
- the `button`-element doesn't stretch and is centered

I'm not sure which browser default style property for buttons causes this.

**How can I make the `a`-element to behave like the `button`?**

*So, the element is centered but not stretched.*

Comment: display:table; ... (text align center and line-height to vertical align)

Comment: by the way, width:fit-content is also a good solution now so you can keep the display:flex

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for finding the dupe. It didn't came up on my search. `width: fit-content;` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Use `inline-flex`

```css
.button {
  appearance: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

a.button {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: lightblue;
}

body {
text-align:Center;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#">a-element</a>
<button class="button" type="button">a-element</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately `inline-flex` will stop `margin: auto` from working and the element is not centered anymore.

Comment: Then you can center it but adding `text-align:center` to the parent.

Comment: Yeah, but if I don't need to center everything in the parent, then I need to add another wrapper for the button. I thought there might be a way to circumvent this.

Answer (score -1):

It's just because of display : flex,  can be solved with inline flex

EDITED

```css
.button {
  appearance: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.btn-container{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <a class="button">a-element</a>
  <button class="button" type="button">a-element</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately `inline-flex` will stop `margin: auto` from working and the element is not centered anymore.

Comment: if you want to  center the button you can put them in a div and add text-align center. 
SEE MY UPDATED ANSWER

Comment: Yeah, but if I don't need to center everything in the parent, then I need to add another wrapper for the button. I thought there might be a way to circumvent this.

Comment: in this case, you need a wrapper, then you can use position: absolute with relative wrapper or simply text align center